# I need to rewrite the url , eliminate the folder name externaly only

Tags: .htaccess, web, url, redirect

I need to hide the folder name from url my current Url is :

https://www.domain.co.uk/OrderformVWP3.2/order.php

OrderformVWP3.2 is folder name where orders.php is located but dont want show OrderformVWP3.2 this in URL
need something like :
https://www.domain.co.uk/order.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^OrderformVWP3.2/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

but its showing 404 error.

Comment: You may check this article it will help you out :https://www.coodingdessign.com/more/some-useful-htaccess-rules-developer-must-know/

Answer (score 1):

Your rule returns a 404 error becacuse `RewriteRule ^OrderformVWP3.2/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]` redirects `/OrderformVWP3.2/order.php` to `/order.php` . Since the **order.php** file doesnt exist in your root folder you get a 404 error.
Instead of URL redirection , you need to internally rewrite your URL from new path to the new orignal one .

The following rule should work in your `/.htaccess` .

```
  +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^order\.php$ /OrderformVWP3.2/order.php [L,NC]
```

Now with the above rule you can visit `/OrderformVWP3.2/order.php` even without using the folder name in URL.

Comment: hi amit thanks for replying ..... your code works for me but the it is making an error which my domain in runnig the index.php file like when i hit domain.co.uk its showing the directory list all files and folder